# Java Map Reduce of HTML file: missing objects after mapping

Tags: java, regex, mapreduce, missing-data

We're trying to implement a mapreduce algorithm which is supposed to work with an html file. The file itself contains Facebook profiles, and the goal is to find friend connections.
Our program first reads each line and has the line number as a key, line as the value. After that, the mappig starts:

```
public class MWFriendExtractMapper <KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>
    extends MWMapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {

private String profileId = null;
private boolean newProfileHasStarted = false;


@Override
protected void map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN value,
                   MWContext<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> context) {
    String line = (String) value;


    Pattern profileStart = Pattern.compile("<title>.*</title>");
    Matcher mProfileStart = profileStart.matcher(line);

    //search for profile start:
    if(mProfileStart.matches()) {
        this.newProfileHasStarted = true;
    }

    Pattern profileId = Pattern.compile(".*name=\"next\".*");
    Matcher mProfileId = profileId.matcher(line);


    //search for id of owner:
    if(this.newProfileHasStarted && mProfileId.matches()) {



        String[] lineInfos = line.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < lineInfos.length; i++) {
            if(lineInfos[i].contains("value")) {
                String address = lineInfos[i];
                String[] addressInfos = address.split("/");
                String id = addressInfos[addressInfos.length -1];
                this.profileId = id.replace("\"", "");
            }


        }

    }

    Pattern pfriendId = Pattern.compile(".*rel=\"friend\".*");
    Matcher mFriendId = pfriendId.matcher(line);

    //search for friends of profile owner:
    if(this.newProfileHasStarted && !(this.profileId == null) && mFriendId.matches()) {
        String[] lineInfos = line.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < lineInfos.length; i++) {
            if(lineInfos[i].contains("href")) {
                String address = lineInfos[i];
                String[] addressInfos = address.split("/");
                String friendId = addressInfos[addressInfos.length -1].replace("\"", "");
                try {
                    context.write((KEYOUT) this.profileId, (VALUEOUT) friendId);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the superclass MWMapper:

```
public class MWMapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> implements Runnable {

private MWContext<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> context;

/**
 * Sets MapContext
 * @param context
 */
public void setContext(MWMapContext<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> context){
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * Starts mapping-thread
 */
public void run(){
    //while there is another key-value in the list...
    while(this.context.nextKeyValues()) {
        for (VALUEIN value : this.context.getCurrentValues()) {
            //... map them
            this.map(this.context.getCurrentKey(), value, this.context);
        }
    }
    try {
        this.context.outputComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * mapping method
 * @param key       key of value
 * @param value     
 * @param context   Context to use
 */
protected void map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN value, MWContext<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> context) {
    try {
        context.write((KEYOUT) key, (VALUEOUT) value);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

The problem is that the **outputfile misses several profiles** (we list the friend connections as ID\t IDs of friends). And the really weird thing is that, **the more mapper we use, the less profiles we're missing.** So it's probably no issue of regexs...
(and yes, we make sure that the mappers get entire profile blocks)

I'm pretty sure that no one can solve this for us, but maybe someone had a similar problem once or an idea, what the hell is wrong with this...

Thanks!

P.S.: here're the HTML tags:

```
    ### Searchpattern ###

+++ Profile start +++

- <title>
- example:

    <title>Allan Thompson | Facebook</title>


+++ ID of profile owner +++

- id="next"
- example for ID "0zzymandias":

    <input type="hidden" id="next" name="next" value="http://www.facebook.com/0zzymandias" autocomplete="off" />


+++ relationships +++

- rel="friend"
- example for ID "730106348":

    <a class="title" href="http://www.facebook.com/people/Charles-Ongele/730106348" rel="friend" title="Charles Ongele"><img class="UIProfileImage UIProfileImage_LARGE img" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-sf2p/hs310.ash1/23250_730106348_713_q.jpg" alt="Charles Ongele"></img></a>



### additional information ###

+++ data-small.dump +++

- 2530 Profiles
- 40244 relationships

+++ data.dump +++

- 25278 Profiles
- 395344 relationships
```

Comment: The while loop is outside of the mapper class. Sorry, should have added that!

Comment: Never mind, I need to read the code for a bit longer.